# What was Hades doing by the time Atlas was destroying the Pillar of the World?

Tags: god-of-war-chains-of-olympus

In GoW Chains of Olympus, when the Fire Steeds approach the realm of Hades they disappear and it's said that those being of light weren't welcome in that place.

So (I believe) Helios' power had no influence over the realm of Hades, which means (if I'm correct) that the god Hades wouldn't be affected by the deep slumber caused by Helios' absence that affected the other gods.

It's also said that Kratos could see the bright of Helios at great distance, when in the depths of Hades. And that makes me think that Hades was aware that Atlas was released but he didn't do anything about it.

Why didn't Hades help to stop Atlas? Considering that the destruction of the World was not his desire (because he had no reason for that)? Please, **I'm looking for sourced answers**.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: There are some users on the site that don't think lore questions should be allowed. That would be my guess.

Comment: I think this is a game of, "Poke the plot hole."  Unless it's directly answered in the plot, chances of getting a good answer is extremely low.

Comment: Well, the FAQ says "Plot and characters in games", I though lore was included...

Comment: @Flutter Its confusing to say that people don't think they should be allowed.  Downvotes do not equal should not be allowed.  Downvotes equal not a useful question.

Comment: [Link to Meta discussion](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5522/can-i-make-questions-about-lore-in-arqade)